# splitting and renaming repeated columns in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, dplyr

I'm very new to R and working on tidying a data set. I have a large number of columns, where some columns (in .CSV file) contain several comma separated names. For example, I need to split and duplicate the column and give the comma-separated-names individually to each column:

[image]

However, I may have more complicated situation, where there are several columns (with different numerical values) with the same repeated multiple names. these column should be split (each column for each name) and to the repeated names should be added suffixes ('.1' or even '.2' if they repeated more times), see here:

[image]

I am actively exploring how to do it, but still no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a minimal & representative example include sample data. If unsure how to do that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This sounds like a job for `strsplit` or `tidyr::separate_rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

First lets create some dummy example data using `data.table::fread`

```
library(data.table)    
dt = fread(
"a b c,d e f,g,h
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5", sep=' ')
#   a b c,d e f,g,h
#1: 1 2   3 4     5
#2: 1 2   3 4     5

cols = names(dt)
```

Now we use `stringr` to count occurences of commas in the names, and add columns accordingly.  We use recycling in the `matrix` statement to fill new adjacent columns with the same values

```
library(stringr)
dt.new = dt[, lapply(cols, function(x) matrix(get(x), NROW(dt), str_count(x, ',')+1L))] 
names(dt.new) <- unlist(strsplit(cols, ','))
dt.new
#    a b c d e f g h
# 1: 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5
# 2: 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5
```

Similarly, in case you prefer to use a base `data.frame` rather than `data.table` we can instead do

```
dt.new = data.frame(lapply(cols, function(x) matrix(dt[[x]], NROW(dt), str_count(x,',')+1L)))
names(dt.new) <- unlist(strsplit(cols, ','))
```

Comment: great answer, many thanks, however I still have a problem, while reading the .csv file. Each column name which contains two names separated by ","  are converted to "." For example: 'P123, Q456' in csv file will be converted into 'P123.Q456'. Any ideas?